# Как вставить новый элемент в родительский элемент

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qtreewidget

Не пойму, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на `item` добавлялся дочерний `item`, а то у меня получается так, что добавляется в корневой `item`.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
import os

# path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Conv(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 400)

        self.tree = QTreeWidget(self)
        self.tree.header().hide()

        self.btn = QPushButton('Add', self)
        self.btn.move(300, 200)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.addy)

        # self.fileTree()
        self.items()

    def items(self):
        item = QTreeWidgetItem()
        item.setText(0, 'Начало')
        self.tree.addTopLevelItem(item)
        q = QTreeWidgetItem(item)
        q.setText(0, 'Hello')



    def addy(self):
        if self.tree.selectedItems():
            b = QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
            b.setText(0, 'New')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    conv = Conv()
    conv.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QTreeWidgetItem::[**QTreeWidgetItem**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#QTreeWidgetItem-7)(QTreeWidgetItem *parent, QTreeWidgetItem *preceding, int type = Type)
>
> Создает элемент виджета дерева указанного типа,
> который вставляется в родительский элемент после предыдущего дочернего элемента.

```
import sys
import os
'''
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *                               # PyQt6
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *                                      # PyQt5

# path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
# ??? path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Conv(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 400)

        self.tree = QTreeWidget(self)
        self.tree.header().hide()

        self.btn = QPushButton('Add', self)
        self.btn.move(300, 200)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.addy)

        self.items()

    def items(self):
        item = QTreeWidgetItem()
        item.setText(0, 'Начало')
        self.tree.addTopLevelItem(item)
        q = QTreeWidgetItem(item)
        q.setText(0, 'Hello')

    def addy(self):
        items = self.tree.selectedItems()
        if items:
            b = QTreeWidgetItem(items[0])                 # <---- items[0]
            b.setText(0, 'New')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    conv = Conv()
    conv.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]